# Reducir espacios Button en Tabla

Tags: bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Amigos una Consulta como Puedo hacer que la tabla tengo menos espacio, agrege un boton a la tabla y se agranda el row  quisiera tenerlo menos ancho

Este es el Codigo del Boton:

```html
<td>
<div class="dropdown-inverse btn-sm dropdown open">
    <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-out-dotted btn-sm btn-out-dotted dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light " type="button" id="dropdown-7" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Opciones</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-7" data-dropdown-in="fadeIn" data-dropdown-out="fadeOut">
        <a class="dropdown-item waves-light waves-effect" href="#">Cancelar</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item waves-light waves-effect" href="#">Renovar</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item waves-light waves-effect" href="#">Editar</a>
    </div>
</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que veo estás utilizando Materialize, este framework trabaja aplicando el atributo `padding` a las etiquetas `td` y `th` de tu tabla, por defecto vienen así:

```
td, th {
    padding: 15px 5px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 2px;
    }
```

Reduce los pixeles en `padding` para disminuir el espacio entre el contenido de la celda y el borde de la misma:

```
td, th {
    padding: 2px 5px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 2px;
    }
```

```css
td, th {
    padding: 2px 5px!important;
```

```html
<head>
 
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>            
  
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  
</head>

<body>

   <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Item Name</th>
              <th>Item Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Alvin</td>
            <td>Eclair</td>
            <td>
<div class="dropdown-inverse btn-sm dropdown open">
    <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-out-dotted btn-sm btn-out-dotted dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light " type="button" id="dropdown-7" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Opciones</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-7" data-dropdown-in="fadeIn" data-dropdown-out="fadeOut">
        <a class="dropdown-item waves-light waves-effect" href="#">Cancelar</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item waves-light waves-effect" href="#">Renovar</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item waves-light waves-effect" href="#">Editar</a>
    </div>
</div>
</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Alan</td>
            <td>Jellybean</td>
            <td>
<div class="dropdown-inverse btn-sm dropdown open">
    <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-out-dotted btn-sm btn-out-dotted dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light " type="button" id="dropdown-7" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Opciones</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-7" data-dropdown-in="fadeIn" data-dropdown-out="fadeOut">
        <a class="dropdown-item waves-light waves-effect" href="#">Cancelar</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item waves-light waves-effect" href="#">Renovar</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item waves-light waves-effect" href="#">Editar</a>
    </div>
</div>
</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jonathan</td>
            <td>Lollipop</td>
            <td>
<div class="dropdown-inverse btn-sm dropdown open">
    <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-out-dotted btn-sm btn-out-dotted dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light " type="button" id="dropdown-7" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Opciones</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-7" data-dropdown-in="fadeIn" data-dropdown-out="fadeOut">
        <a class="dropdown-item waves-light waves-effect" href="#">Cancelar</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item waves-light waves-effect" href="#">Renovar</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item waves-light waves-effect" href="#">Editar</a>
    </div>
</div>
</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

  

</body>
```

También podrías usar el atributo `cellpadding` dentro de tu tabla, pero [no se recomienda su uso por ser obsoleto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/table).

Puedes ver más información sobre el uso en tablas del atributo `padding` en [este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/padding).